# java.lang.classcastexception in mainservice.java

Tags: android, sms, recovery

I am making an android application for mobile theft recivery as my final project. its main activity seems to have some problem. The logcat keeps giving the error java.lang.classcastexception in mainactivity. And the application gives error of unexpected problem and needs to be shut down. here is my code. Please point me out where the problem is. Thanks.

```
package com.example.mainsms;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainService extends Service implements Runnable
{
    TravelPhoneStateListener mPhoneListener;
    static TelephonyManager tm;
    //TextView txt_lat,txt_lon,txt_adr;    
    public static String call_alert_no="";
    public String response_phno="", current_cell_id="", 
            standard_cell_id="", ph_imei="", ph_imsi="", initialization_flag="true", 
            alert_nos[]={"0331", "0324"}; 
    public boolean profile_ph=true;
    static boolean call_alert_flag;  
    static SmsManager sms;
    AudioManager maudio;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("Inside oncreate MainService");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside on create MainService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid)
    {
          System.out.println("Inside onstart MainService");
          Toast.makeText(this, "Inside onStart MainService", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          mPhoneListener = new TravelPhoneStateListener(MainService.this);
          MainService.tm = ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
          MainService.tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); 
          System.out.println("Inside Onstart MainService");  
          sms = SmsManager.getDefault();   
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          try
          {
                //properties.load(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/system_file.properties"));
                initialization_flag=properties.getProperty("initialization_flag");
          }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

          FindIMEI_IMSI();
          if(initialization_flag.equals("false"))
          {
              try{
                properties.setProperty("initialization_flag","true");
                standard_cell_id=ph_imei+ph_imsi;
                properties.setProperty("standard_cell_identity",standard_cell_id);
                //properties.store(new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/system_file.properties"),null);
              }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
          }
          else
          {
                standard_cell_id=properties.getProperty("standard_cell_identity");;
          }

            current_cell_id=ph_imei+ph_imsi;
            System.out.println("standard_cell_identity : "+standard_cell_id);
System.out.println("current_cell_identity  : "+current_cell_id);

            if(!standard_cell_id.trim().equals(current_cell_id.trim()))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<alert_nos.length;i++)
                {

                    sendSMS(alert_nos[i],
                            "SIM changed. Note IMEI number  => "+ph_imei);
                    try{Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }       

            Thread th=new Thread(this);
            th.start();
            System.out.println("After Thread Started");
    }


    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside Run methode");
      while(true)
      {
        if(SMSReceiver.flag)
        {
          String sms_received=SMSReceiver.msg;
          String token=sms_received.substring(sms_received.indexOf("-")+1,sms_received.lastIndexOf("-"));
          if(token.trim().equals("INout"))
          {
            SMSReceiver.flag=false;
            profile_ph=false;
            SMSReceiver.msg="";
            call_alert_no=sms_received.substring(sms_received.lastIndexOf("-")+1); 
            call_alert_flag=true;
          }
          else if(token.trim().equals("profile"))
          {               
                  profile_ph=false;
                  String mode="";
                  SMSReceiver.flag=false;
                  SMSReceiver.msg="";
                  mode=sms_received.substring(sms_received.lastIndexOf("-")+1,sms_received.indexOf("@"));
                  response_phno=sms_received.substring(sms_received.indexOf("@")+1);
                  if(mode.trim().equals("RingAndVib"))
                  { 
                      maudio=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                      System.out.println("...C...Profile ring-and-vib");
                      maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                      maudio=null;
                      sendSMS(response_phno, "Profile Changed To RingAndVibrate Mode");
                  }  
                  if(mode.trim().equals("silent"))
                  {
                    maudio=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    System.out.println("...C...Profile silent");
                    maudio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                    maudio=null;
                    sendSMS(response_phno, "Profile Changed To Silent Mode");
                  }
           }
           else
           {
                    if(profile_ph)
                    {
                        response_phno=sms_received.substring(sms_received.lastIndexOf("-")+1); 
                        SMSReceiver.flag=false;
                        SMSReceiver.msg="";
                        sendSMS(response_phno,"Invalid Request");
                    }
           }
                    SMSReceiver.flag=false;
             } 

         }
      }



    public static void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        System.out.println("Inside Send SMS phone No"+phoneNumber+"Message "+message);
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);        
    }  

    public void FindIMEI_IMSI()
    {
        TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String p_imei = manager.getDeviceId();
        String p_imsi = manager.getSubscriberId();
        if(p_imei!=null && p_imei.length()==15 ){
             ph_imei=p_imei;
             //txt_lat.setText(ph_imei);
             ph_imsi=p_imsi;
            // txt_lon.setText(ph_imsi);
         }else{
             ph_imei=p_imei;
             ph_imsi=p_imsi; 
         }
    }
}
```

here is the logcat

[image]

Comment: If mainactivty is the problem, why have you put MainService in to your question?

Comment: where is MainActivity ?

Comment: acccording to   java.lang.classcastexception you missing Binding Control with some wrong class Object

Comment: this code is of mainservice which has some problem @sir jcw

Comment: +1 Good Topic, can you please upload your log cat with question ?

Comment: stack trace from logcat?????

Comment: yes sir @ lucifer and sankar V , I would have but it is not allowing me to upload pix since i have 10 reputation marks. i am new here.

Comment: 04-06 16:56:56.844: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mainsms.MainService

This is the logcat main error

Comment: put here your MainActivity Code

Comment: this is my main activity code named as main service.java @sir anki